# How to select one to one relations from many to many table

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have a database where i keep books and their authors. In my model, one author can have many books, and one book can be written by many authors. Example:

```
AUTHOR_ID|BOOK_ID
1|100
1|200
1|300
2|300
3|300
4|400
```

I'm trying to get authors that have exactly one book written, and that book must be written only by that author alone. In above example only valid author is with AUTHOR_ID = 4.
I need to write one select for getting author ids which fullfills above requirement, how can i write fast and efficient select to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from BookAuthors t1
where not exists (select * from BookAuthors t2
                  where t2.BOOK_ID = t1.BOOK_ID
                    and t2.Author_ID <> t1.Author_ID)
  and not exists (select * from BookAuthors t3
                  where t3.Author_ID  = t1.Author_ID
                    and t3.BOOK_ID <> t1.BOOK_ID)
```

The first `NOT EXISTS` is there to make sure same bookid doesn't have a second author.

The second `NOT EXISTS` is there to make sure same Author_ID hasn't written another book.

Combined version:

```
select *
from BookAuthors t1
where not exists (select * from BookAuthors t2
                  where (t2.BOOK_ID = t1.BOOK_ID
                         and t2.Author_ID <> t1.Author_ID)
                     or (t2.Author_ID  = t1.Author_ID
                         and t2.BOOK_ID <> t1.BOOK_ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a separate answer because the first was just wrong.

If your database supports window functions, one method is:

```
select Author_ID
from (select ba.*, count(*) over (partition by Author_ID) as numBooks,
             count(*) over (partition by Book_ID) as numAuthors
      from BookAuthors ba
     ) ba
where numBooks = 1 and numAuthors = 1;
```

There are also various ways to do this by moving the conditions to the `where` clause or `join`s:

```
select ba.*
from BookAuthors ba
where Author_ID in (select Author_Id from BookAuthors group by Author_Id having count(*) = 1) and
      Book_ID in (select Author_Id from BookAuthors group by Book_ID having count(*) = 1);
```